# How to determine the instantaneous acceleration of each box right after the connecting thread is cut?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Consider the following diagram. The system is in equilibrium. When the red thread is cut, determine the magnitude and direction of instantaneous acceleration of each box? Neglect the mass of the thread and spring.

[image]

In my mental model, the $M$ will be accelerated by $mg/M$ upward and $m$ will be accelerated by $g$ downward. Is it correct?

### My calculation

For $M$, there are $k\Delta y=(M+m)g$ force upward and $Mg$ downward. The net force is $mg$ upward, so the acceleration is $mg/M$ upward.

For $m$, there is only one force, $mg$ downward, so the acceleration is $mg/m=g$ downward.

Comment: Just say yes or no  please. No need to explain the details.

Comment: Yup, looks good to me.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: OK. Thanks. Now I can proceed to do other things. :-)

Comment: @OlinLathrop: IMHO, my profile picture has nothing to do with honor. It is monthly changed just for fun. I will change it next month, the second week probably. :-)

Comment: Some programmers use unit testing to mock the code, I use my face to mock it. It is the idea behind my profile picture.